# Get Iphone User Wallpaper?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, wallpaper

In xcode, is it possible to get the image file that is currently being used at the user's wallpaper? I would like to display it as a background in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible through public API-s, however if you wanted to use it as an iOS7 `UIWindow` background, maybe [this question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aSRLVyViwn2AJ%3astackoverflow.com/questions/21906869/how-to-get-the-current-homescreen-wallpaper-on-ios%20&cd=1&hl=hu&ct=clnk&client=safari) will help you.

If you are jailbrooken then you can find the images there:

Homescreen: `/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackground.cpbitmap.`

Lockscreen: `/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.cpbitmap.`

*When wallpapers are the same there will be only one of those files.*

[source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aSRLVyViwn2AJ%3astackoverflow.com/questions/21906869/how-to-get-the-current-homescreen-wallpaper-on-ios%20&cd=1&hl=hu&ct=clnk&client=safari)